# Memory bug and related

Tags: c++, memory-management

Ugh! I think I've got one of those obscure memory bugs. But I am not sure. It's possible it is not even in my part of the code. I am testing a (C++) application on MS VC++ 2005. Right now, my code throws a exception and breaks due to some heap error at a seemingly harmless vector push back:

```
std::vector<int> blah;
for(int i=0; i<somesize; ++i) {
   blah.push_back(0);
}
```

No matter where I move this segment of the code, the failure happens exactly at the push back. This is crazy! I am sure there is nothing illegal about this usage. Also, when I comment it out, it goes past it without any issues. Above and below it I have other vectors which I am able to load without any troubles. Related to that I have another question about doing this:

```
std::vector<double*> wha;
wha.push_back(nil);
..
... 
wha[0] = some pointer I create;
```

The question I have is: when wha goes out of scope, it shouldn't delete the pointer, right? I think I'm right on that, but better to clarify. I am sorry, there isn't much detail, but let me know if any additional details help and I'll try and post more. Thanks.

Edit:

The exact error message is:

```
First-chance exception at 0x771b70cd in myprogram_run.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: 
H5::FileIException at memory location 0x08026ca0..
First-chance exception at 0x771b70cd in myprogram_run.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: 
H5::FileIException at memory location 0x08026ca0..
'myprogram_run.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\wdmaud.drv', No symbols loaded.
...
...
''myprogram_run.exe': Unloaded '<path\to>\bin\win64-x64-vs2005.shared\tcl85.dll'
The thread 'Win64 Thread' (0x23a8) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'Win64 Thread' (0x120c) has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).
The thread 'Win64 Thread' (0x27bc) has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).
...
...
HEAP[myprogram_run.exe]: HEAP: Free Heap block dfd6870 modified at dfd68d0 after it was freed
Windows has triggered a breakpoint in myprogram_run.exe.

This may be due to a corruption of the heap, and indicates a bug in myprogram_run.exe or any of 
the DLLs it has loaded.

The output window may have more diagnostic information 
The program '[3052] myprogram_run.exe: Native' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).
```

Should I be concerned about the H5::FileIExceptions? We do link to it as a 3rd party DLL.

Comment: One question topic per post, please...

Comment: Naked pointers in containers have to be deleted explicity, hence the need for smart pointers. And what does debugging show ? And why **push_back(0)**, not push_back(i) ?

Comment: You need to get a [minimal example *that reproduces your problem*](http://sscce.org). The code posted does not have the problem, so no one can help you without guessing wildly. Chances are that while trying to narrow down to such an example, you'll find the issue yourself.

Comment: Can you minimize the code? That is, remove everything *else* that you can, without changing the (bad) behavior. Eventually you'll either find the bug or get something small enough to post. For the second question, no, it should not attempt to delete the object pointed to.

Comment: Thanks all, I'll try to post a concise example (non-trivial since I have no clue yet where the issue is) or dig deeper.

Comment: @squashed.bugaboo there are tools to fight against with memory corruption. On Linux, valgrind is terrific. I am confident that you can find similar things on Windows.

Comment: A coworker of mine had a very similar issue when iterating a vector... turned out that the previous function call was to an external library, and the header that call was declared in had specified the wrong calling convention, which was wreaking havoc on the stack.  So it might be something completely unrelated to the vector.

Answer (score 3):

1. The code you posted is fine. A memory corruption may have happened somewhere else, and the `push_back` is only revealing it.
2. `nil` will not be deleted. Every time you use `push_back`, a copy of the pointer is pushed into the vector. The only thing that is deleted is the internal array containing all the copies of the pointers.

Answer (score 1):

In general, the first thing you should do upon experiencing heap corruption is to enable some form of "debug malloc", most platforms have this.

On VC++2005, apparently you can just `#define _DEBUG`. This turns malloc() into [_malloc_dbg()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/faz3a37z%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), which includes debugging information (such as file/line) and padding to check for buffer overruns/underruns. See also [The CRT Debug Heap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/974tc9t1%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

**EDIT:** If that doesn't help (and often it does not), you can use a debug malloc that puts a "guard page" after each allocation, e.g. [DUMA](http://sourceforge.net/projects/duma/) or OSX's `libgmalloc`. This is not enabled by default on debug builds because the overhead is huge (up to ~8K per allocation), but makes debugging the problem *much* faster (and catches the bad access instead of a subsequent call to malloc()/free()/the heap-checking function).

(I recently fixed a ~weekly crash that I've been putting up with for *years* — possibly over a decade! I'm not sure how it didn't occur to me to do this earlier, given that I've known about libgmalloc for nearly as long and used it to debug heap corruption at work.)

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific, though. Where should I define #define _DEBUG? Also wouldn't that be the equivalent of running in debug mode? (i.e., such a pre-compiler directive should automatically be set when running in debug, no?)

Comment: I just tried this.. it didn't really give me any more info than I was already seeing.

Comment: Actually, I figured out how and did this right (Project->Properties->C/C++->PreprocessorDefinitions); as well as I had to add the includes and pre-processor definitions in main()
#define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <crtdbg.h> and the call to  _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();  but I am not getting the detailed output with line #s etc.. Any ideas?

Comment: I would expect it to appear near the `Free Heap block ... modified at ... after it was freed` message, though it's possible that the file/line information is cleared when the block is freed. Answer edited to include DUMA.